# Missing data in Text box in a infopath 2010 form

Tags: infopath2010

I have a infopath 2010 form with a table and couple of text boxes and this form is configured to submit a email with the form in the body of the email.

The form is opened in a browser and I am able to add text and submit the form and I see the email. But the form ( with data ) in the body of the email has lost formatting and the text field on the form was set to a width of 100% and as a 'Multi line ' text and I see that the data in the text field as we see on the email body is chooped off.

I am having issues controlling the format of the form as we seen in the browser and they way it shows up on the email body.

Any help is appreciated.

Sri

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem to. The way that I got around this is by creating another view for the form and then having the exact same layout but changing all the controlls so that they are calculated fields this then seems to give you the values.

thanks, Jack